# Another way to say "to become a better person"

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, phrase-requests, synonyms

When I'm asked the generic question, "why do you do community service?" I usually respond by saying

"because it makes me a better person," or

"because doing community service allows me to develop as a person."

What are some common synonyms or other ways of saying "to become a better person"?

Comment: To contribute to the society.

Comment: "because it helps me [to] improve myself"

Comment: self-improvement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word ***edify*** has many meanings, mostly now historic ones. But OED sense 3a, seems to me what you are looking for.

*Becoming a better person* suggests a spiritual enhancement. So it seems you are seeking ***edification***. (Not to be confused with *education*.)

> 3a. trans. In religious use: To build up (the church, the soul) in
>   faith and holiness; to benefit spiritually; to strengthen, support.
>
> 1876   E. A. Freeman Hist. Norman Conquest I. App. 751   He was much
>   edified by the king's prayers and almsdeeds.

Comment: All the answers were helpful, but I guess my question could have been clearer. It should have been named another way to say "to grow as a person," and technically this response best answers that.

Answer (score 2):

You could/should examine within yourself what that means to **you**. The answers might differ depending on your motives and belief system.

**Spiritually uplifting** This suggests that you are seeking an awareness beyond your current definition or understanding of spirituality.

**Spiritually satisfying** You are providing service so that you can return to a place that helps you to feel wholesome and good.

**Because I feel it's my responsibility** This does not have bearing on "becoming a better person" per se, but it is what a good person should do.

**To become a better person** suggests that you are not happy with the person you are or that you have sins (for lack of a better word) that you feel you owe penitence for.

**Because it makes me feel good about myself** This sounds like an affirmation. Service generally receives gratitude and positive feedback, thus it  can help with self-esteem issues.

**It's not about me** This is a bit abrupt, but gets to the heart of community service: if I were in a situation that required compassionate assistance, then I hope somebody would come to my aid.

**It seems like God gave me lots of gifts, and I'm showing my gratitude by giving back to those in need** This has more of a universal tone compared to the me/them examples.

Comment: I think these are good definitions, but what would also be an alternative phrase to "developing as a person"?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. Perhaps I should have written it as "I give my time because I find it to be spiritually uplifting," and so forth. I guess I'm suggesting a deep examination of what combination of personal, spiritual, practical, or selfless principles are in play and wouldn't be the same from person to person.

Answer (score 0):

You might say, it allows you to *[evolve](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evolve)*

> to change or develop slowly often into a better, more complex, or more advanced state : to develop by a process of evolution

*Merriam-Webster*